# How can we see the UI of an android application for different screen sizes at the same time

Tags: android, user-interface

When develop an android application, I need to adjust the font size, width, height, padding for different screen, e.g. small/normal/large/xlarge

I'm using Intellij-Idea now, but I see the UI for only one screen at a time, it's not very convenient. How can we see it for different screen sizes at the same time? Is there any tool to do this?

Comment: Doesn't Android SDk has this feature of switching among different UI sizes in the Emulator ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Eclipse you can view XML in a "Graphical Layout" tab in the XML editor.

In the "Graphical Layout" you can specify what screen size you would like to view the preview in.

You can open several XML editor panes and arrange them to be side by side.

If these things aren't available in Intelli-J I suggest switching to Eclipse which is the focus of the Android Tools Team's development AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

you need to have different folders for different layout i.e

layout-small

layout-large

layout-xlarge

Also you must have three types of drawable folders with three different sets of images.i.e

drawable-small

drawable-large

drawable-xlarge

The Android UI automatically fetches the layout and images according to the mobile screen.